# WCF/MSMQ Transport Security with Certificates

Tags: wcf, certificate, msmq

my goal is to secure the communication between `MSMQ` Queue Managers – I don’t want unknown clients sending messages to my `MSMQ` server.

I have spent many hours now trying to get `Transport` security working for the `net.msmq` binding in `WCF`, where `MSMQ` is in `Workgroup` mode and the client and server do not have `Active Directory`… so I’m using certificates.  I have created a new `X.509` certificate, called `Kristan` and put it into the “`Trusted people`” store on the server and into the My store of `Current User` of the client.

The error I’m getting is:

> An error occurred while sending to the queue: `Unrecognized error -1072824272 (0xc00e0030).Ensure that MSMQ is installed and running. If you are sending to a local queue, ensure the queue exists with the required access mode and authorization`.

Using smartsniff, I see that there’s no attempted connection with the remote `MSMQ`, however, it’s an error probably coming from the local queue manager.  The stack trace is:

```
 at System.ServiceModel.Channels.MsmqOutputChannel.OnSend(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.OutputChannel.Send(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.OutputChannelBinder.Send(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)
```

The code:-

```
EndpointAddress endpointAddress = new EndpointAddress(new Uri(endPointAddress));

            NetMsmqBinding clientBinding = new NetMsmqBinding();
            clientBinding.Security.Mode = NetMsmqSecurityMode.Transport;

            clientBinding.Security.Transport.MsmqAuthenticationMode = MsmqAuthenticationMode.Certificate;
            clientBinding.Security.Transport.MsmqProtectionLevel = System.Net.Security.ProtectionLevel.Sign; 

            clientBinding.ExactlyOnce = false;
            clientBinding.UseActiveDirectory = false; 

            // start new
            var channelFactory = new ChannelFactory<IAsyncImportApi>(clientBinding, endpointAddress);


            channelFactory.Credentials.ClientCertificate.SetCertificate("CN=Kristan",
                StoreLocation.CurrentUser,
                StoreName.My);
```

The queue is flagged as ‘Authenticated’ on the server.  I have checked the effect of this and if I turn off all security in the client send, then I get ‘Signature is invalid’ – which is understandable and shows that it’s definitely looking for a sig.

Are there are special ports that I need to check are open for cert-based msmq auth?

Comment: Did you ever get this worked out?  I'm having the same issue, except I'm also using Message Security and that's my hangup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at http://www.controlsystemworks.com/articles/CertificateSecurityForWcfOverMsmq.html

I think you need to set-up both client and server cerificates.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem and could not figure this out. However, I get slightly different error message `0xc00e002c` but situation is the same - trying to use `Transport` security with `Certificate` but it simply does not work. If I use the same certificate for message security it works fine.

By the way - if i impersonate `ASPNET` process to run as current user (which has more rights) everything works as expected (no errors). I have also found certificate file and added the same all possible `permissions` to `ASPNET` account but that does not help either.